# How to get the size of arrays packed as value in a Dictionary<K,V> in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, nested-loops

I have a `Dictionary<K,V>` object already filled with data:

```
Dictionary<string, double[]> ltableData;
```

Every `double[]` has the same size (number of elements).

I do not know in advance neither any **'string' key** nor the size of the '**double[]' values**.

Now I have to make one cycle with a nested one as follows:

```
 for(int i = 0; i< number_elements;i++)
 {
    foreach (var array in ltableData.Values)
    {
        ltempList.Add(array[i]);
        //other instructions
    }
 }
```

How can I assign **number_elements**? I can of course use this solution:

```
var lrowCount;
foreach(var item in ltableData.Values)
{
  lrowCount = item.Count();
}
```

that works but it is of course ugly both to see and execute. Is there any cleaner and more effective method to extract the count? Thanks

Francesco

Comment: your first nested loop didn't make sense - what are you trying to do? In the second loop you just re-assign the same value - also doesn't make sense.

Comment: Indeed, doesn't `Dictionary<string, double[]>.Add` take a `(string, double[])` pair? You are trying to pass it a single `double`.

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Sorry it is a typo now it is correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var lrowCount = ltableData.Values.First().Length;
// or
var lrowCount = ltableData.First().Value.Length;
```

Comment: @Francesco: this is a very roundabout way of accomplishing what you want (manually finding the length, then manually doing two nested loops). See my answer for a solution that uses a single built-in method.

Answer (score 3):

You can take its length from any item:

```
int number_elements = ltableData.Values.Select(v => v.Length).FirstOrDefault();
```

Though I think if you have such structure then you should create a class for it which will have a `Length` on top level and which will also assert and guarantee that all inner items have the same length.

Comment: A check for any elements should be performed first, otherwise this code might throw. OP needs to consider what the length is in this case.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (var array in ltableData.Values)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        //other instructions
    }
}
```

or, even more readable,

```
foreach (var array in ltableData.Values)
{
    foreach (var val in array)
    {
        //other instructions
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not answer the question, which was how to extract the count

Comment: @Domenic: No, but I believe it solves the underlying problem and makes the question redundant.

Comment: And I believe it will throw an exception since you're updating `ltableData` while iterating over it.

Comment: @Snowbear: True. I just copied that from the OP; that line makes no sense even in the original. I’ll remove it.

Comment: @Timwi I see what you were trying to do now. Maybe clarify that with text next time for those of us who jumped on Stack Overflow 5 minutes after waking up :P. Also it says my vote is locked in; will try to fix whenever it lets me.

Comment: @Timwi, Oops, I didn't notice that original question has the same issue, my comment should be there.

Comment: @Domenic @Timwi @Snowbear JIM-compiler: There was a typo in the initial question that made everubody confused. Sorry about that. If it can be of any help I am filling a ViewModel where the keys of the Dictionary<K,V> are the table headers and the values represent the column for each header. In order to use foreach or an extended html helpers I need to traspose the values

Answer (score 2):

If you know that itableData does contain values you can do the following.

```
ltableData.Values.First().Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to say this is much cleaner, but you could do

```
var number_elements = ltableData.Values.First().Count();
```

This is ONLY if you must need the length.  Otherwise, a foreach loop would be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've clarified what you're doing as per the comments on your original post, it's clear that you actually want

```
using System.Linq;

var ltempList = ltableData.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value);
```

This will give an `IEnumerable<double>` containing all of the values from all different entries in the dictionary, aggregated together.

Comment: thanks for your answer. However I need just a value. The array stored in the Dictionary as value have all the same size. Once I obtain the size of one array the job is finished. Your expression does a differet job

Comment: @Francesco: OK, then why did you include those two nested for loops in your question? My code replaces them, without the intermediate step of getting the size.

Comment: I am filling a ViewModel where the keys of the Dictionary<K,V> are the table headers and the values represent the column for each header. In order to use foreach or an extended html helpers I need to traspose the values

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to get the total number of values

```
var number_elements = ltableData.Select(p => p.Value.Count()).Sum();
```